# Post slug changed using code doesn't reflect on editor when post is published

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, slug

I've a CPT (lets say `Event`) with a custom date field (`start_date`). I'm trying to generate the post slug (`post_name`) as `start_date` + `post_title` (separated by `-`).

I've tried using the filter `wp_unique_post_slug` as well as `wp_insert_post_data` to modify `post_name`. When I publish the post, the slug gets changed internally but it doesn't reflect on admin UI. Only when I refresh the page (edit the post again) the new slug gets displayed properly.

What could be the reason and how do I ensure that the generated slug gets displayed immediately when I publish the post?

---

One observation: `wp_unique_post_slug` filter is invoked 4 times when I publish the post. Out of the 4 invocations only 3rd invocation gets the any data in `$_POST` and in turn the logic for editing the slug gets executed only during 3rd invocation.

Here is the code sample that I'm using, if that helps:

```
public function cpt_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
    if( ! in_array($post_type, array('Event', 'CPT2') ) ) return $slug;

    error_log(var_export($_POST, true));

    if(isset($_POST['start_date'])) {
        // remove any date from post slug
        $slug = preg_replace( '/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-/', '', $slug );
        $slug = $_POST['start_date'] . '-' . $slug;
    }

    return $slug;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are using Gutenberg in which case this is non-trivial problem.

Gutenberg saves post data in two steps (two separate http requests, just use developer tools in your browser to check). First, using REST API it saves Gutenberg-ready fields including title, content and slug. Problem is, REST API uses JSON and `$_POST` is empty array during this save action, so your `wp_unique_post_slug` hook runs but does nothing. Moreover, metabox/custom field values are not even sent in this JSON request.

Then Gutenberg does another POST request to save other fields, which include old-style metaboxes and Custom Fields. This time `$_POST` values are available, so your hook is able to update slug value. However this is too late for Gutenberg to change visible slug value in admin interface, as it was done during first request.

This is interesting problem for me, as I had similar use cases in past, but those sites are still using Classic editor. No time for complete solution now, but I would try to create Gutenberg block for your `start_date` field, set it to store value as meta fields (default for blocks is save inside content field) and add it as mandatory block for your Event CPT, and then try to hook `wp_unique_post_slug` during REST API call. Just don't forget, that you don't have `$_POST` values and should use `$request` object provided by REST API to get `start_date`. A lot to learn about Gutenberg blocks and REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines. Will take a look at Gutenberg blocks. +1 for now.